# awk filtering live capture with file as pattern list

Tags: text-processing, awk, tshark

What I'm trying to do is quite simple. I'm generating output from `tshark` and redirecting it to `awk` with a pipe `|`. Since `tshark` gets live data, I want that `awk` search in every output for a pattern (some MAC addresses that I already have) in the first column in a file ("target.txt") and, if there's a match, `awk` should output the first and second column from this file.

Example from `target.txt`:

```
ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl,Me
12:34:56:78:90:10,You
1b:2d:3f:4h:5j:6l,someone
```

To make it all easier, my `tshark` output has only 2 columns, and the MAC address column is the second one.

1 line of `tshark` output is like:

```
Jun 16, 2014 02:55:51.300286000 12:34:56:78:90:10 
           ^^^^- date and MAC are separated by tab!
```

So if `tshark` finds `12:34:56:78:90:10`, `awk` will output

```
12:34:56:78:90:10 -> You
```

or even better:

```
Jun 16, 2014 02:55:51.300286000 12:34:56:78:90:10 -> You
```

#### EDIT #1

Well, I did some tests and find out that `tshark`s output is separated by `tab` \t. It's not a big deal, but already a small improvement. The thing is, I got samples from `tshark` output and tested with Gnoucs answer through a `echo` command before the pipe `|` . It worked.  Then I changed the `echo` for `tshark` and everything stopped working =).

Is it a problem with the live data or something like that? Here's my code until now:

```
$ tshark -I -i wlan0 -T fields -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal -e wlan.sa | awk -F'[ ,\t]' '
     FNR == NR { a[$1] = $2 }
     ($NF in a) { print $0" -> "a[$NF] }
 ' alvos.txt -
```

well, it just worked! It was probably a typo.
Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F'[ ,\t]' '
    FNR == NR { a[$1] = $2 }
    ($NF in a) { print $0" -> "a[$NF] }
' target.txt -
```

Example:

```
$ awk -F'[ ,\t]' '
    FNR == NR { a[$1] = $2 }
    ($NF in a) { print $0" -> "a[$NF] }
' target.txt -
Jun 16, 2014 02:55:51.300286000 12:34:56:78:90:10 # Ctrl + D here
Jun 16, 2014 02:55:51.300286000 12:34:56:78:90:10 -> You
```

**Explanation**

- `-F[ ,\t]`: we use comma, space or tab as field separators.
- `FNR == NR { a[$1] = $2 }`: `FNR == NR` only true when processing first file. So with each line in `target.txt`, we save the second field to an associative array, with the first field (MAC address) is the index.
- `($NF in a)`: When reading the input (`-` after `target.txt` causes `awk` reading from input), if the last field is in associative array `a`, we print the desired result.

Comment: @mikeserv: No, just in my test. In the OP's case, he just have to pipe output of `tshark` to `awk`.

Comment: @mikeserv: that line is user input on stdin from Gnouc, hence the Ctrl+D to signify EOF.

Comment: No, I get it now - with a pipe that's not a problem, but you were reading from the terminal. Thanks, @Gnouc.

Comment: @DMurta: Fixed. Add `\t` to field separators.

Comment: Found that out too! Thanks!
Your response is very good, but I've edited my question with the (last?) problem. I know the answer is very close
=]

Comment: oh wait, it just worked. Probably typo!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, either one of these will at least generate your desired output:

```
${TSHARK} |
sed -n "$(IFS=',
';  printf '/%s/s//& -> %s/p\n' \
        $(cat target.txt)
)"


${TSHARK} | 
sed -n "$(
   sed 's/,/|s||\& -> /
        s/.*/\\|&|p/
   ' <target.txt
)"
```

I tested this in the following way:

```
printf 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl,Me
12:34:56:78:90:10,You
1b:2d:3f:4h:5j:6l,someone' >./target.txt

printf 'Jun 16, 2014 02:55:51.300286000 12:34:56:78:90:10' |
sed ...
```

And this was my output:

```
Jun 16, 2014 02:55:51.300286000 12:34:56:78:90:10 -> You
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk
# filename ~/mac-lookup.awk

function load_mac_list (filename, array) {
    while ((getline line < filename) > 0) {
        split(line, fields, ",");
        array[fields[1]] = fields[2];
    }
    close(filename)
}

BEGIN {
    load_mac_list("target.txt", mac_list);
}

($5 in mac_list) {
    print $0 " -> " mac_list[$5];
    next;
}

{
    print;   # remove this line to avoid printing unmatched lines
}
```

Here's the brute force approach.    Load the target file, then print the mac alias only if the mac address is in the list.

Note in this case, the "target.txt" is hardcoded in the awk script.  In Gnouc's answer, you can script the target list filename as desired.

**Usage**

```
$ ${TSHARK} | awk -f ~/mac-lookup.awk
Jun 16, 2014 02:55:51.300286000 12:34:56:78:90:10 -> You
Jun 16, 2014 02:55:51.300286010 zy:xw:vu:ts:rq:po
Jun 16, 2014 02:55:51.300286020 ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl -> Me
```